# What do I need to use a headboard?

Tags: furniture, bedroom

[image: headboard with metal bed frame]

I am hoping to get a headboard like [this one](http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=20132395a&category=A_FURN_FURNITURE_BED). What do I actually need to use it? Is the common option to use a metal bed frame or is there some other type of bed structure that I should be using with it?

Comment: I think that You can use any bed structure (frame) You want as long as You will provide vertical support for the headboard. Well, if You place the bed just at the wall (headboard between bed and wall), it's not quite necessary (given that the headboard will stand still), but any proper connection between headboard and bed (wooden/steel frame) is ok.

Comment: The link you provide for the headboard says *"This velvet headboard attaches to your bed frame simply and easily ... hardware included"* It seems to lack legs like the one in your picture though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason that the headboard has to be attached to the bed frame.  I have slept quite soundly at the houses of family members where the headboard was a freestanding fixture or attached to the wall and the bed sat on the floor next to the headboard.

Comment: Headboards should be screwed to the wall or they get... noisy.

Comment: @Mazura:  Perhaps, though one arrangement had a little space between the bed and the headboard, so it was completely silent.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mine is attached exactly as in your photo, but it sure is squeeky because of the inability to stabilize completely.